# No matching mac found: client hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256 server hmac-sha1

Tags: perl, ssh

I am getting below error while running my script, I am on AIX

```
Reading configuration data /ecmsq1vg1/home1/aradmin/.ssh/config
Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
Connecting to www.mftcatapp.firstdataclients.com, port 22.
Remote version string: SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_1.1.8
Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_1.1.8
Net::SSH::Perl Version 2.14, protocol version 2.0.
No compat match: Sun_SSH_1.1.8.
Connection established.
Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), waiting for response.
No matching mac found: client hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256 server hmac-sha1 at /apps/perl/lib/site_perl/5.18.1/aix-thread-multi/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 273
```

Can anyone help me out why i am facing the above error?

Answer (score 1):

[`perldoc Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl):

> Integrity checking is performed by the `hmac-sha2-256`, `hmac-sha2-512`, `hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com`, or `hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com` algorithms. The deprecated `hmac-sha1` or `hmac-md5` algorithms are available but not enabled by default. Many older SSH server installations still use hmac-sha1 as the main accepted MAC algorithm. To enable this, use the following options parameter:
>
> ```
> options => [ "MACs +hmac-sha1" ]
> ```

So either configure your server not to use `hmac-sha1` for integrity checking or tell your script to accept `hmac-sha1`.

Comment: So either configure your server not to use hmac-sha1 for integrity checking or tell your script to accept hmac-sha1         How?

Comment: @RijuMukherjee For the server: No idea, I've never used Sun SSH. Check its manual? As for the script: What's unclear about the code snippet I quoted?